# Getting the real locations of curve point of animated curves with Animation Nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes, sverchok

I can get the actual points or parametric  points of a curve using spline info and the spline evaluate nodes however none of these gives me the real point locations of a curve if the curve is animated with shapekeys or modifiers.

Is it possible to get such info with AN? I guess if that does not work I am ok with doing this in Sverchok.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what curve do you mean?
There are at least two ways:
import gist to sverchok with copy this address and pressing import on sverchok import panel
https://gist.github.com/213c384b46a4a961f0d03300175ce6af
[image]